# How can I use strongly-typed resources in server tags?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to change over some ASP.NET code to use the strongly-typed translations we're using in the C# code. Currently the code looks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:Blah1,Blah2 %>' />
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<% Translations.Blah1.Blah2 %>' NavigateUrl="#" />
```

The reason is that we have a custom provider used in the first case, and it doesn't play nice with aspnet_compiler, and we're trying to eliminate issues caused by aspx/ascx files that don't compile.

However, if I change the code (as shown above), I get this error:

```
Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.
```

Is there any way to achieve this without having to use <%# Databind %> tags and then ensure Databind is called? Using `<%= %>` doesn't work either (presumably because it writes directly to the response stream, but I need to have it set the property).

*EDit*: I need to this programatically across thousands of files, so moving it to a code-behind file is not an option :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find is to put the resource between opening/closing tags. This only works with some controls, so others will need to be changed.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="#"><% Translations.Blah1.Blah2 %></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Is your answer still true? I'm doing something similar and curious if you were able to resolve using the attributes of a tag instead of the inner html.

Comment: Did you ever try using the implicit resource expressions like <asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="hyperLink1" Text="" meta:ResourceKey="hyperLink1Translation" />

Comment: @MADCookie Sadly not, we currently use the "inner html" (content), and where this doesn't work, set them from code (though we don't like this). We were trying to avoid meta:ResourceKey, for the same sort of reasons as <%$ Resources.

Comment: Ultimately we're hoping to move from WebForms to MVC, so this problem will disappear :-)

Comment: Thanks for following up on such an old question & my comments. I appreciate your time & detailed responses.

Answer (score 0):

Give the hyperlink an ID, and set the text property from the code-behind.

Extra advantage: you split your logic from presentation and filling up their respective values

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to do this programatically (across thousands of files), so this isn't a suitable option :-(

Comment: What's not programmatic about this code? And I see it would cost you some time this way, but it's a better solution imho.

I don't even know if this is possible because you use a server side tag (by using runat). I've had problems with this before myself, by trying to usecode nuggets to fill up my link and script includes. It worked for the link references, but not for the script references.

Comment: I have to make these changes programatically across thousands of files. Opening and parsing code-behind files to inject the code that does this in the right place (and at the right time) is not a trivial task.

Comment: i don't know of any other way, and there is no legit reason to do it from your aspx. One of the ideas behind web controls design (and primary function for the code-behind file), is the separation of code binding from your HTML.

Comment: There are perfectly legit reasons to do it from the ASPX - 1) I can't programmtically change it to code-behind and 2) It's just a translated UI string - it's entirely a presentation thing, and I don't want to pollute my code-behind files with thousands of strings needlessly.

Comment: Your first argument, is not a legit reason for using code nuggets in aspx, it's an argument for your specific problem, it doesn't make it correct coding. Secondly, using server side(!) code nuggets within your serverside control is the problem. You could try changing it to this:
<a href="#"><% Translations.Blah1.Blah2 %></a>

Comment: @DannyTuppeny let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2260/discussion-between-rickjaah-and-danny-tuppeny)

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to my specific problem =P Can't chat atm, away from PC for a while